# how to call crystalreport.rpt file in aspx.cs files

Tags: asp.net

how to call crystalreport.rpt file in aspx.cs files    any coding?a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at

- [Crystal Reports in ASP.NET](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Using-Crystal-Reports.aspx)
- [Creating Crystal Report in ASP.NET](http://www.highoncoding.com/Articles/550_Creating_Crystal_Report_in_ASP_NET.aspx)
- [Programming Crystal Reports with
  ASP.NET 2.0](http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/ASP.NET/Programming-Crystal-Reports-with-ASP-NET-2-0/)